# Monoids, Semigroups, and a Reflective Subcategory.

Tags: category-theory, semigroups, monoid

The following is reflective in the category $\mathbf{Sem}$ of semigroups and their homomorphisms: we add a new neutral element to **each** semigroup, even monoids; then the reflections are identity mappings on the old structures, and homomorphisms in this reflective subcategory will preserve the neutral element.

> What if we add neutral elements only to semigroups that are not already monoids? *Why* won't this be a reflective subcategory in $\mathbf{Sem}$? What is the easiest proof of this?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: I really cannot imagine.If reflections are still identities on old structures, then something will fail,and other choice should not be possible,but I cannot see this precisely :(

Comment: It's not a functor.

Comment: Unfortunately,after two days,I still cannot see why...Any further hint?Composition fails--why?

Comment: I've got the point now.My problem was that I draw only one commutative diagram for the adjunction from the two as given in the book CWM.

Comment: Would you not just obtain the full subcategory of those semigroups that
happen to have a neutral element?